# How would I concatenate many rows with the same ID into a single row in SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot

This is the current structure of my table.

[image]

My goal is to have it setup like this:

[image]

What query do I need to do to get this setup?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, postgresql...?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    userId,
    batchId,
    max(case when typeId = 1 then value end) typeId1,
    max(case when typeId = 2 then value end) typeId2,
    max(case when typeId = 3 then value end) typeId3,
    max(case when typeId = 4 then value end) typeId4
from mytable
group by
    userId,
    batchId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot.

```
SELECT userId, batchId, 
[1] AS typeId1,
[2] AS typeId2,
[3] AS typeId3,
[4] AS typeId4
FROM 
(
    SELECT userId, batchId, typeId, [value] 
    FROM yourtable
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value])
    FOR typeId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) pvt
ORDER BY userId, batchId;
```

Test [here](https://rextester.com/ZRXWA5164)